# rails PG undefined column does not exist for index creation

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to add an index for a for column but I'm getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "contact" does not exist
: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_users_on_contact" ON "users"  ("contact")
```

which is strange because as you an see I'm creating the column before I try to index it:

```
class AddContactToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :contact, foreign_key: true
    add_index :users, :contact, unique: true
  end
end
```

Why am I getting this error?

In case your wondering why I'm doing a separate contact model, it's because all users will have a contact but not all contacts will have a user.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_reference :users, :contact, foreign_key: true
```

Creates a column named `contact_id`. So you're index needs to be

```
add_index :users, :contact_id, unique: true
```